# How to run .EXE from .BAT inside the folder where .EXE is locating

Tags: batch-file, cmd

To recreate my problem you need to understand that I have next files in 2 folders.

> K:\Script.bat
>
> K:\Project\PortChanger.exe
>
> K:\Project\settings.xml

I want to launch PortChanger.exe using Script.bat that contains next line:

```
start "K:\Project\PortChanger.exe"
```

This script is actually executing Program.exe, but my program throws me exception since PortChanger.exe can't find Settings.xml.

How can I launch PortChanger.exe from "K:\Project\", not from "K:\"? Now it seems like .BAT taking .EXE code and just running it where .BAT is locating.

To make it even more clear:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Start` with its `/D` option:

```bat
Start "" /D "K:\Project" "K:\Project\PortChanger.exe"
```

Open a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?` to read its usage information.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you rather use `pushd` and `popd`

```
@echo off
pushd "K:\Project"
start "" PortChanger.exe
popd
```

`pushd` will change to the directory, launch the executable from it, then `popd` will return to the previous directory stored.